# Insert and Common Table Expression (CTE) in Ozzie Workflow

Tags: sql, hive, workflow, impala, hue

I would like to have my both Common Table Expression and Insert statement combine together in Ozzie Workflow, but it always failed.

Anyone know how could we write these combination, what are the general codes?

Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert into table A partition(date)
with test as
(select * from table B),
select col A as name1, select col B as name2 from test
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is related to CTE.
can you pls try -

```
insert into table A partition(date) 
with test as (select * from table B) 
select colA as name1, colB as name2, -- correct list columns
inp_date -- partition col will be last col
from test  -- you can select from cte
```

Comment: Last second line
Inp_date, what does it means¿

Comment: Its the partition column data.

Comment: Hi,

Just found the answer, because my code sequence was incorrect.
Here is the sequence of the code and finally it works.

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

with test_CTE as 
(select  *  from table1),

testone_CTE as
(select col1, col2, col3 from test_CTE)

insert into table mytablename partition(biz_dt)
select  col1 as name1, col2 as name2, col3 as name3 from testOne_CTE

Comment: yours and mine both queries are same... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer, because my code sequence was incorrect.
Here is the sequence of the code and finally it works.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

with test_CTE as 
(select  *  from table1),

testone_CTE as
(select col1, col2, col3 from test_CTE)

insert into table mytablename partition(biz_dt)

select  col1 as name1, col2 as name2, col3 as name3 from testOne_CTE
```